# Is there anyway for the pywinauto to access the buttons in the menu bar?

Tags: python, pywinauto

Here is the screenshot from the program:

[image]

Here is the screenshot from inspect.exe:

[image]

I have reached this far with pywinauto, but can't find the means to access the menu bar at all.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto import Desktop, findwindows

app = Application().connect(process=4632)
win = app.top_window()
```

Comment: I would suggest to search in unit tests how they work with menu for MFC apps: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/tree/atspi/apps/MFC_samples (just search by executable name in all .py files). Also `Application(backend="uia")` has some workarounds for "disconnected children" problem for some menus.